# Cannot install perl module on Windows

Tags: perl-module, activeperl

How to install `Template::Plugin::GD`to ActivePerl

I tried,

```
ppm install Template::Plugin::GD
```

but got error

```
ppm install failed: can't find any package that provides Template::Plugin::GD
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ActivePerl V5.24, the PPM repository for this version is not available yet. Please try V5.22 as I have tried this version and it installs for me.